# Which message queue allows to see progress of a batch of messages?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue

I updated the question to answer comments of @Deadpool and @Nicolas :

We are currently using RabbitMQ. 
We have a multi-step process (Step1, Step2, Step3).

**Step1**: publish 100 messages to the queue with a grouping-key "batch1" (e.g. 100 JSON Products for HTTP API requests, so that products will be inserted/updated in an online shop). Workers should process the the batch1 in parallel ([Worker Queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html)) for example 4 workers a 25 messages. The main goal is parallel execution of the "batch1" for performance reasons.

**Step2**: should start working only if all 100 messages of step1 have been consumed / processed (e.g. all products have been inserted / updated).

So that means that either *step2* needs to wait until all 100 messages of "batch1" have been consumed / processed by n workers

e.g.

```
if (isNoMessageLeft(step1){
  // do step2 work
}
```

or *step1* should do the waiting before continuing to step2.

e.g.

```
if (isNoMessageLeft(step1){
  // continue to step2
}
```

*Step2* may need to work on results of *Step1*, but maybe not. 
It is just important that *Step1*, *Step2* and *Step3* are processed if the predecessor has been finished. It is a little bit comparable to the *Read-your-own-writes* concept in databases.

We have not yet found a way to do such message grouping in RabbitMQ only. We could track the progress in an extra database (each consumer updates a counter table or so), but we would avoid it if possible. Ideally the queue allows something like this.

At the moment Step1-3 are completely serial (one single Thread in a Java app), but we would like to to improve using a Worker Queue approach to utilize a cluster of multiple workers for certain tasks.

How could something like this be approached? (ideally with RabbitMQ) or with another queue product e.g.

Is this possible with Apache Kafka?

Comment: can you be more specific? i believe you can do it, could you give more explanation ? why next process should wait until batch1 consumed ? and how?

Comment: Is the second process also acting on `batch1`? If so, why don't you republish `batch1` to RabbitMQ so that it ends up in a different queue drained by the second process after it has been handled by the first consumer? If the same first process should just wait until all messages in `batch1` were processed before dealing with `batch2`, set the prefetch count to the size of your batches and wait until you're done before you acknowledge the messages?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Deadpool. I clarified the question.

Comment: @Nicolas: Meanwhile I have updated the question. I will investigate into the prefetch idea.  But I the batch size is always different. 100 was just an example. It is basically process specific and configurable by the user (it is a ETL workflow software). e.g. userA wants to import a batch of 500 products and userB imports a batch of 25000 products.

Comment: Thanks for updating, i guess kafka will not be perfect match for your business requirement, 1) if you are posting 25000 message to kafka with same key then they all go to same partition and consuming all those will take more time (since at most one consumer thread can be assigned to one partition) think if you have dependency like step3 after step2 and step2 after step1, you will really lack performance on it

Comment: Ah I see. If you want to do it with RabbitMQ, an idea could be that each `step1` worker (that takes at most N messages) sends a message back indicating it processed m items from `batch1`. Then you can have another service accumulate those messages and publish another message to signal to `step2` that `batch1` is ready (provided it knows how many items were in `batch1` initially). Depending on how many batches you handle concurrently and how long the process takes, you'd maybe better use an external DB to maintain the count of processed items. I don't see how Kafka would do better.

Comment: "Batching" and "Messaging" are two separate (conflicting) job strategies. Can you provide some parameters? Size of each "step 1" message, along with typical processing time.

Comment: Thanks @theMayer, that is a good angle I haven't thought about. 
Size of each "step 1" message differs: it could be a JSON with typical product data e.g "name, description, price, stock". It varies per customer. 
I would agree that what we want to do is more "batching". But currently we use RabbitMQ to distribute the "messages" to a cluster of workers for distributed processing. What can you recommend for such "batching" tasks instead?